# Discord Py bot receiving and forwarding a DM to a specified server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having some trouble with my bot. I'm trying to have the bot work so that if it receives a DM with the command "appeal  ", the bot would send the appeal to the server's #appeal channel. This is what I've got so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def appeal(ctx, guild_id, *reasons):
    '''Command for a user to DM the bot with an appeal, and have that appeal sent to the corresponding server.'''
    
    # Checking if the command is invoked in a DM

    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):

        # Finding the guild through the provided guild id

        bot.guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)

        # Finding and assigning a text channel called "appeals", and sending the appeal to that channel

        appeals = discord.utils.get(bot.get_guild(guild_id).text_channels, name="appeals")
        await bot.guild.appeals.send(f"**{ctx.author.id} has appealed to this server:** {reasons}")
```

This is the traceback I'm receiving however:

```
Ignoring exception in command appeal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/secret/Desktop/OneDrive/PyBot/Millenium_Build.py", line 408, in appeal
    appeals = discord.utils.get(bot.get_guild(guild_id).text_channels, name="appeals")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text_channels'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text_channels'
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: what intents have you enabled?

Comment: I enabled server members intent but not presence inten. @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: You mean `intents.guilds`?

Comment: I meant the intents in the developer portal. I just enabled intents.guilds though and that didn't do the trick, same error. I've only got intents.members enabled otherwise

Comment: check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you didn't enable any intents, DM's messages needs `intents.dm_messages`, `get_guild` needs `intents.guilds`. Also you can use the `commands.dm_only` decorator instead of that `isinstance`. Also the **IDs MUST BE ALWAYS INTEGERS**

Here's how to enable intents:

```py
# Enabling default intents (everything apart from privileged ones)
intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also here's the `dm_only` decorator in use

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def appeal(ctx, guild_id: int, *, reason):
    # ...
```

Also you can get the `guild` and `appeal` channel in the `on_ready` event, no need to get it everytime the command is invoked

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.main_guild = bot.get_guild(some_guild_id) # You'd need to hardcode this
    bot.appeals = discord.utils.get(bot.main_guild.text_channels, name='appeals') # I'm not sure why it's not possible with `bot.main_guild.appeals`, but this should work

# Now you can simply bot.main_guild.appeals.send('some content')
```

Comment: Thanks! After having done that though, I'm getting another error but this one's on the last line which remains unchanged from my main post: "AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'appeals'".

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed through a command are all strings by default. `bot.get_guild()` only works with an integer.

Either you can pass `int(guild_id)` to the function, or edit your command parameters to automatically transform it into an integer like this

`async def appeal(ctx, guild_id: int, *reasons):`